# Sorting Datatables with dashes and dots

Tags: jquery, datatables

I found a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16408690/2167386) for this question but I still have problems. If you put in the second column values like 1.5 or 1, the sorting will be wrong. How can this be fixed? Thanks a lot! I edited the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CYubV/7/

```
<table id=table>
    <thead><tr><th>Normal</th><th>Nullable</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>15</td>
           <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>4</td>
           <td>1.5</td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use ParseFloat to handle the comparison between the whole integers and the decimals. [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jGX9q/)

```
var ia = parseFloat(a);
var ib = parseFloat(b);
```