# DataTables sorting/ordering column with special chars

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I'm using [DataTables jQuery plugin](https://datatables.net) to add sorting/ordering to my table. I had to add special char `*` to some numbers in column. When I did it sorting/ordering became working incorrect.[image: As you can see, first value on <code>korteri nr</code> is 1 then 10 and etc.. but there is 2, 3 and others which are on lower position if scroll]
As you can see, first value on `korteri nr` is 1 then 10 and etc.. but there is 2, 3 and others which are on lower position if scroll

I have tried this code to achieve correct ordering, but it doesn't help

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['custom-sorting-asc'] = function(a,b) {
        a = escapeRegExp(a);
        b = escapeRegExp(b);
        return (a == b) ? 0 : (a > b) ? 1 : -1;
    };
    $.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['custom-sorting-desc'] = function(a,b) {
        a = escapeRegExp(a);
        b = escapeRegExp(b);
        return (a == b) ? 0 : (a > b) ? -1 : 1; //reverse sorting
    };


    function escapeRegExp(string){
        return string.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
    }

    $('.handp-table').DataTable( {
            searching: false,
            paging: false,         
            aoColumns: [
                { "sType": "custom-sorting" }, //custom sorting
                null, //default sorting
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
            ]
        } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found another solution for this problem. I changed logic which generated column content. Instead of adding `*` to every number where should be this character I added class to this element `some_class` and then used `CSS pseudo element :after` to add `*` as content. `DataTables` doesn't count css so it is working now as should.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that datatables is interpreting the values in that column as strings, and sorts them alphabetically.

You can try using the render function in the appropriate column:

```
aoColumns: [
                { fnRender: function(data,type,full){
                       if(type==='sort'){
                           return data;
                       }
                       return data+'*';
                  } 
                }
                null, //default sorting
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
            ]
```

I assume the data you are retrieving from the server is plain integers. If this is the case, then Datatables will be smart enough to cast and use the integer value for sorting, and use the integer value with a concatenated `*` (i.e.: a string) for displaying, filtering, etc.

By the way, if you're using Datatables 1.10+, I'd suggest you use the new syntax (is clearer and easier to use)

Comment: I'm using `DataTables v 1.10.11` . There is a situation, when I can use counter to set the number for each inside loop, but depending on data which came form the server I should add `*` . So it's simple concatination now like `if(true) $counter . '*'` . Backend is on `PHP`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler way, and more flexible: You can add the attribute `data-order` to each `td` tag, which will then be used to order. I've given a more detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51225222/8801891